# How to zip folder content and save zip with Foldername in same Folder

Tags: zip, 7-zip

Hi I'm trying to zip the Folder Content and save the zip in the Folder with the Foldername:

OS Windows 10

```
Folder1
      File1.jpg
      File2.jpg
      File3.jpg
      Folder1.zip
Folder2
      File1.jpg
      File2.jpg
      File3.jpg
      Folder2.zip
.... and so on
```

Comment: Linux or windows?

Comment: Windows. The app itself doesn't matter

Comment: with a script that decompresses and then moves to that new folder ... then I believe it if it is not answered before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), move to the parent directory (common base for `Folder1` and `Folder2`, then run, from Cygwin:

`for de in $(ls); do cd ${de}/; zip ${de}.zip *; cd ../; mv ${de}/${de}.zip ./; done`

[I guess you would need this too](http://superuser.com/questions/544225/ddg#544226).

<sub><sub>**DISCLAIMER**: I'm not responsible for data losses direct or indirectly caused by the either correct or incorrect use of the provided command line.</sub></sub>

Comment: i get the following error:

`zip error: Nothing to do! (1.zip)
mv: der Aufruf von stat für '1.zip' ist nicht möglich: No such file or directory`

also there are spaces in the Foldername

Comment: okay i replaced all the spaces with "_". But the zip File contains a Folder and not only the Files `Folder_1.zip -> Folder_1 -> File1.jpg,File2.jpg...`

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry for the entries with spaces. :(

Comment: Oh, didn't want the Folder directory at the zipped doc, didn't realize that at first.

Comment: Thank you now it works. And don't worry for the spaces. i can bulk rename the folders and files.